# Django: use archive_index with date_field from a related model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-generic-views

Hello (please excuse me for my ugly english :p),

Imagine these two simple models :

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.db import models

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('object id'))
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    published_at = models.DateTimeField('Publication date')


class SomeOtherModel(models.Model):
    related = generic.GenericRelation(SomeModel)
```

I would like to use the archive_index generic view with SomeOtherModel, but it doesn't work :

```
from django.views.generic.date_based import archive_index

archive_index(request, SometherModel.objects.all(), 'related__published_at')
```

The error comes from archive_index at line 28 (using django 1.1) :

```
date_list = queryset.dates(date_field, 'year')[::-1]
```

The raised exception is :

```
SomeOtherModel has no field named 'related__published_at'
```

Have you any idea to fix it ?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From digging through the Django source code, the generic view `archive_index` does not appear to support related fields that are `GenericRelation`s.

This is because the queryset method `dates` does not support generic relations. Consider filing this as a bug / feature request on the Django bug tracker.

Comment: This still seems to be the case as of Django 1.8